# Connect Java- Application to MongoDB - com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

Tags: java, mongodb, jboss

In my application I use MongoDB and it works fine locally with Wildfly 11.0.0.Alpha1 - after deployment at local application server and local MongoDB database the application is reachable at context path and port - erverything is fine.

My next step was to deploy this application to JBoss server at a server maschine.
I changed the MongoDB URI to a mongoDB Server:

```
mongodb://user:password@server:27017/databaseName?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&ssl=true
```

If I deploy this application I get the following log entry at bottom. 
Actually I don't know why and what it means. 
Has anyone a hint what I can do in this case to solve it ?

```
08:38:42,249 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (cluster-
ClusterId{value='59b62f7238b5cb310bd6f438', description='null'}-myServer:27017) Exception in monitor thread while connecting 
to 
server myServer:27017: com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely 
reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88) 
[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    atm com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:494) [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:224) [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveReply(CommandHelper.java:134) [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:121) [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32) [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:85) [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:45) [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:116) [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) [mongodb-driver-core-3.4.1.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_112]

08:38:42,855 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 290) No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description 
ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=
[ServerDescription{address=myServer:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the timeouts occurring on the connection with the mongodb.
try to increase the timeouts by using API when you build your connection

```
  MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(<long_time>);
```

Or try to remove them that said no timeout